# How to save image with desired name and type via Prima::SaveDialog?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to save the file **img.png** present in my code folder to another file with desired name, at desired location.

```
use Prima qw(Application Buttons StdBitmap FileDialog MsgBox PodView); 

my $save = Prima::SaveDialog->new(
    text     =>'Save Image',
    fileName => $save->fileName,
    filter   => [
        ['PNG Image' => '*.png'],
    ],
);

if ( $save->execute ) {
    my $x = Prima::Image->load('img.png');
    die "$@" unless $x;
    die "$@" unless $x->save( fileName);
}

run Prima;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.  There's big syntax error around the variable `$save`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The code may be like this:

```
use Prima qw(Application Buttons StdBitmap FileDialog MsgBox PodView); 

my $save = Prima::SaveDialog->new(
    text     =>'Save Image',        
    filter   => [
        ['PNG Image' => '*.png'],
    ],
);

if ( $save->execute ) {
    my $x = Prima::Image->load('img.png');
    die "$@" unless $x;
    die "$@" unless $x->save($save->fileName); <--------------------changed.
}

run Prima;
```